# Make URL queries readable for php

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to implement some php on an Apache 2+ Server which I do not have root access of. One script has to receive variables in a URL, but the API, that sends me the data, generates a URL-String with a `#` character in it.

The URL in Question would look like this:

```
http://website.name.com/script.php#foo=1&bar=2
```

Is there any way for the `foo` and `bar` variables to reach the `script.php`? I've read in other answers that everything after `#` doesn't get parsed by the server, so I tried to use an `.htaccess` file with a `RewriteRule` to replace the hashtag, but I was unable to create a working RegEx command.

Answer (score 0):

No, the thing isn't that it isn't *parsed* by the server, the issue is that it's never *being sent* to the server. Everything after `#` is a *local* anchor, and is only available inside the current browser context (so Javascript would be able to read it, as it runs in the current browser context).

Since it's never sent to the server, you can't rewrite it or read it (since it doesn't exist) on the server side.

What you *can* do, is create a small bit of Javascript on the resulting page in `script.php`, and then submit that back to the server side - either through a redirect or through a fetch or xmlhttprequest.

To recreate the request as a GET request with the same parameters as given in the local anchor, you can use `location.hash` and remove the `#`:

```
location.href = 'realscript.php?' + location.hash.substring(1);
```

.. but I would consider parsing the hash yourself and then doing whatever is necessary in Javascript explicitly instead of redirecting like that.